# Solving my Unhandled Runtime Error with Next JS + Stripe

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

Repo: https://github.com/DoctorSte/aiAdvisor.git

I'm trying to get a Next app to work with Stripe, but I keep getting an
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: An error occurred while performing this request.
when I try to initiate the Stripe Checkout session on the paymentPage.ts.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"; 
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { createCheckoutSession } from "next-stripe/client";

interface IPrice extends Stripe.Price {
  product: Stripe.Product;
}

interface IProps {
  prices: IPrice[];
}

export default function Home({ prices }: IProps) {
  const onClick = async (priceId: string) => {
    const session = await createCheckoutSession({
      success_url: window.location.href,
      cancel_url: window.location.href,
      line_items: [{ price: priceId, quantity: 1 }],
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      mode: "payment",
    });
    const stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY);
    if (stripe) {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-24">
      <h1>Buy Stuff</h1>

      <ul>
        {prices.map((price) => (
          <li key={price.id}>
            <h2>{price.product.name}</h2>
            <img className=" rounded-md" src={price.product.images[0]} />
            <p>Cost: ${((price.unit_amount as number) / 100).toFixed(2)}</p>
            <button onClick={() => onClick(price.id)}>Buy</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul> <br />
 <Link href="/"><a>Back home</a></Link>
    </div>
  );
}


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
    apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
  });

  const prices = await stripe.prices.list({
    active: true,
    limit: 0,
    expand: ["data.product"],
  });

  return { props: { prices: prices.data } };
};
```

Any idea what might be going on here?
This is the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: An error occurred while performing this request.

Call Stack
_callee$
node_modules/next-stripe/dist/lib/fetcher.js (51:0)
tryCatch
node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (63:14)
Generator.invoke [as _invoke]
node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (293:0)
Generator.eval [as next]
node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (118:0)
asyncGeneratorStep
node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js (3:0)
_next
node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js (25:0)
```

I'm using the Next JS Stripe packgage.

Comment: The repo link at the top of your question doesn't work (404).  Also wondering if you can provide more information about which specific line of the code you shared throws the error?  Are you seeing any errors in [the logs in your Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs)?

Comment: Sorry about that, just realised it was set to private. It's public now.
Dashboard seems clean, no error logs, but it's a good starting point since now I now it's not even trying to initiate checkout.
It doesn't say which line causes the error, it just happens when I click buy on the product page (trying to initiate Stripe checkout).

Comment: Can you add logging to see where specifically the code is failing?  Are there any errors or useful information in the web developer tools under the console or network tabs when you click the button?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! 
It's the API key from the looks of it, under web dev tools I get a: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)", 
{"message":"You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.","status":401}

I know what to look for now.

Comment: Ah, yep, sounds like `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY` isn't being set for some reason.

Comment: I got the same error as you and was able to fix it by following [this](https://vercel.com/guides/getting-started-with-nextjs-typescript-stripe) tutorial. (Note, the example repo accompanying the tutorial has changed since the tutorial was written so you have to look at the repo at the time of [this commit](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/f7baa56792cf8566954f762b961260a00c476994/examples/with-stripe-typescript).)